# How to add a close button on slidedown

Tags: html, css

Having this as a working slidedown,

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
            background: transparent;
            }
        /* optional: show position indicator in red */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background: #FF0000;
            }
        @-webkit-keyframes slideDown {
            0%, 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-485px); }
            10%, 90% { -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
            }
        @-moz-keyframes slideDown {
            0%, 100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-485px); }
            10%, 90% { -moz-transform: translateY(0px); }
        }
    .cssanimations.csstransforms #note {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-485px);
        -webkit-animation: slideDown 20.5s 1.0s 1 ease forwards;
        -moz-transform:    translateY(-50px);
        -moz-animation:    slideDown 20.5s 1.0s 1 ease forwards;
    }
```

html:

```
<div id="note">
    {{=XML(news)}}
</div>
```

I need to add a button for the user to close the slide in case she does not want to read the information. Without adding / using js How do I do it?
Regards

Comment: can you add some rendered html?

Comment: Hi loved_by_jesus, what have you tried so far and what is preventing you from advancing? (What is your main problem?) Please refer to the following [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please provide us of a working example containing your specific problem.

Comment: @loved_by_Jesus if you wanted to hide the div on click you could add some simple js, that when clicked (e.g. a button , update the css of the div to display:none; ) No jquery or anything like that necessary..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you'll get to a CSS click is the `:active` selector.

First you'll need to change your HTML so that your `{{=XML(news)}}` is wrapped in a `div` tag.

```
<div id="note">
  <p>Won't be affected.</p>
  <div id="sub-div">{{=XML(news)}}</div>
</div>
```

Next add this to your CSS:

```
#note:active #sub-div {
  display: none
}
```

Now when you *"click"* the element it'll be hidden and when you *"click"* something else, it'll be shown again.

**NOTE:** the `p` tag won't be affected by this CSS since we're only selecting the `div` tag.

You could also try use the `:hover` selector, like this:

```
#note:hover #sub-div {
  display: none
}
```

Which would hide the child element on `:hover` and reveal it when the user moved the mouse away from `div#note`.

**NOTE:** You could reverse this process by hiding the element then showing it on `:active`/`:hover`.

Good luck.

Comment: you don't need to precede #note by div in css. #note>div would also work (but it's better to give the XML div an id of it's own. )

Comment: Thanks @LogicalBranch. This works well. Currently the element slides and stays for the 20.5seconds, any way of just closing it if one does not want to read it?I appreciate.

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @loved_by_Jesus You're very welcome and no, if you'd like to hide the div for good or remove it, you'd have to use a JavaScript `click` event listener. Unfortunately CSS doesn't support event listeners.

Comment: Ok. Noted. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to LogicalBranch, Rachel...I got it this way:

$(document).click(function() {
        if(this != $("#note")[0]) {
            $("#note").hide();
        }
    });